# Как построчно вывести весь список Python?

Tags: python

Как построчно вывести весь список Python ???

Comment: http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/mod/book/view.php?id=4901

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
t = [1,2,3]
```

Допустим, это будет наш список

```
for x in t:
    print(x)
```

Или так:

```
print('\n'.join(t))
```

Comment: Последний способ работает только на списках строк. Чтобы он работал на любом списке, нужно записать несколько иначе: `print('\n'.join(str(value) for value in t))` или `print('\n'.join(map(str, t)))`

Answer (score 3):

```
t = [1,2,3]
print(*t, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tek = (t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7)

print('\n'.join(tek))
```