# Как выводить каждый элемент списка с новой строки?

Tags: python, list

```
y = []
r = int(input('Нужное количество чисел: '))

while r != 0:
  x = int(input("любое число: "))
  y.append(x)
  r = r - 1
print(*y, end='\n')
```

Мне нужно, чтобы каждый элемент, который пользователь внёс в список `y`, выводился с новой строки.

Comment: `sep="\n"`.....

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/251048/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-python