# Список выводиться в одну строчку python

Tags: python, парсер, list, beautiful-soup, bs4

Изучая библиотеку bs4, я пыталась спарсить недостатки и сам отзыв, где их описывают пользователи.
Получился такой код:

```
minus = soap.find_all("div", class_="review-minus")
review = soap.find_all("div", class_="review-teaser")

for item in minus:
    m = item.text

for i in review:
    r = i.text

print(f"{m}: {r}")
```

И он выводит список в одну строчкку, я пыталась разделить его так (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/251051/558317):

```
print("\n".join(f"{m}: {r}"))
```

но это привело к тому, что код выводит каждую букву из списка на отдельной строке. Возможно ли вывести спарсенные данные, например, так:  Недостаток: сам отзыв...?

Comment: У вас циклы фактически не рабочие, в m и r записываются только последние значения (старые значения перезаписываюся новыми). Нужно значения собирать в список, потом выводить.

Comment: поняла, спасибо. попробую сделать все как надо

Comment: посмотрите в сторону функции `zip`

Answer (score 1):

Спустя около часа я поняла в чем проблема и оставлю ответ тут, вдруг кому-то поможет.
find_all итак сама по себе генерирует список, поэтому все циклы, которые я создавала бесполезны и делают список внутри списка.

Теперь мой код выглядит так:

```
minus = soap.find_all("div", class_="review-minus")
review = soap.find_all("div", class_="review-teaser")

done = {}

for d in range(0,len(minus)):
    done[minus[d]] = review[d]
# print(done) - это я проверяла как выводиться словарь

for key, value in done.items():
    print(key.text, ":", value.text)
```

В итоге я получаю:

```
все нормально : Специально искала кроватку из экологичных материалов и покрашенную краской на водной основе. И эта как раз меня устроила по всем параметрам) Есть маятниковый механизм, который помогает мне уложить ребенка. Сразу засыпает) И маятник можно спокойно...

не замечено : Выбирали между тремя вариантами, в итоге остановились на этом и пока еще ни разу не пожалели. Во-первых, здесь все очень толково и грамотно продумано, включая в том числе съемные боковые рейки и одну из стенок...
```